# newAPIHadoopRDD versus Hbase API to read hbase table

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

In my spark project, I need to read the configuration info from hbase table. The data is not much, about thousands of records. There are 2 methods which can be used to do this thing, one is **sc.newAPIHadoopRDD** and the other is **ResultScanner**. Which method should I use please? Which is better approach?

Comment: Neither. https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector

Comment: I think I do not need to convert the data to rdd, because the data size is very small, how about just use the hbase api please, compared to the sc.newAPIHadoopRDD in speed dimension?

Comment: Spark uses RDD (or Dataset if using Spark 2.x) **always**. If you want to use the HBase API directly, then you do not need Spark. If the files are small, you also don't need Spark